# Hibernate Spring bi directional many to many removal not working

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am having an issue while trying to conduct a deletion in a many-to-many relationship. First of all I'd like to mention the story. I have two entity classes called Post and Category, Here Posts are associated with Categories, and it is also true other way around. I can create categories and post, and when creating or editing a post I can associate categories no problem. The issue arises when I remove a category from a post. There is no exception or error thrown, but it does not remove it.

Normally as you will see below the code, in a post set, when I remove a category object and save the object, hibernate will take care of removing the regarding relation in the shared table, but it does not just happen!

Other than that, I've tried multiple solutions, but they did not quite work out either.

1. https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=17
2. [Hibernate Bidirectional ManyToMany delete issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155587/hibernate-bidirectional-manytomany-delete-issue)
   3.http://www.codereye.com/2009/06/hibernate-bi-directional-many-to-many.html
   4.[Hibernate Bi-Directional Many to Many association creates duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228455/hibernate-bi-directional-many-to-many-association-creates-duplicates)
   5.https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-manytomany-unidirectional-bidirectional/

**Post Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "postid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long postId;

    @Column(name = "postTitle")
    private String postTitle;

    @Column(name = "postContext")
    @Type(type = "text")
    private String postContext;

    @Column(name = "postedDate")
    private Date postedDate;

    @Column(name = "visitCount")
    private long visitCount;

    @Column(name = "publishable")
    private boolean publishable;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, targetEntity = Category.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    //@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "posts")
    @JoinTable(name = "post_category", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "postid")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "categoryid")})
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;

    public Post() {
    }

    public Post(String postTitle, String postContext, Date postedDate, boolean publishable, Set<Category> categories, User user) {
        this.postTitle = postTitle;
        this.postContext = postContext;
        this.postedDate = postedDate;
        this.publishable = publishable;
        this.categories = categories;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public long getPostId() {
        return postId;
    }

    public void setPostId(long postId) {
        this.postId = postId;
    }

    public String getPostTitle() {
        return postTitle;
    }

    public void setPostTitle(String postTitle) {
        this.postTitle = postTitle;
    }

    public String getPostContext() {
        return postContext;
    }

    public void setPostContext(String postContext) {
        this.postContext = postContext;
    }

    public Date getPostedDate() {
        return postedDate;
    }

    public long getVisitCount() {
        return visitCount;
    }

    public void setVisitCount(long visitCount) {
        this.visitCount = visitCount;
    }

    public void setPostedDate(Date postedDate) {
        this.postedDate = postedDate;
    }

    public boolean isPublishable() {
        return publishable;
    }

    public void setPublishable(boolean publishable) {
        this.publishable = publishable;
    }

    public Set<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(Set<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

**Category Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "categoryid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long categoryId;

    @Column(name = "categoryName")
    private String categoryName;

    @Column(name = "createdDate")
    private Date createdDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_category_id")
    private Category parentCategory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCategory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<Category> subCategories = new HashSet<>();

   // @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Post.class)
   // @JoinTable(name = "post_category", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "categoryid")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "postid")})
   @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "categories")
    private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<>();

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public Category(String categoryName, Date createdDate, Category parentCategory) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.parentCategory = parentCategory;
        this.subCategories = new HashSet<>();
        if (parentCategory != null) {
            parentCategory.subCategories.add(this);
        }
    }

    public Set<Post> getPosts() {
        return posts;
    }

    public void setPosts(Set<Post> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    public long getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(long categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Category getParentCategory() {
        return parentCategory;
    }

    public void setParentCategory(Category parentCategory) {
        this.parentCategory = parentCategory;
    }

    public Set<Category> getSubCategories() {
        return subCategories;
    }

    public void setSubCategories(Set<Category> subCategories) {
        this.subCategories = subCategories;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
@Test
    public void stage09_EditCreatedPostTest() {
        //Fetch the post
        Post post = appService.getPostByName(postName);

        //Fetch the child category;
        Category category = appService.getCategoryByName(childCatName);

        //Remove the child category
        post.getCategories().remove(category);

        //Selected child category is not null
        assertNotNull(category);

        appService.editPost(post);

        //Fetch the post again
        Post post2 = appService.getPostByName(postName);

        //Check the post2 object it is not null
        assertNotNull(post2);

        //Check category size
        assertEquals(1, post2.getCategories().size());
    }
```

**Edit** 
*Post Edit DAO Method*

```
public void editPost(Post post) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            session.update(post);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            transaction.rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

For a couple of days, I've been googling and checking out different sources and finally I've decided to test entire structure and the entity classes in Non J2EE environments using Hibernate and EclipseLink JPA without Spring. I've come to realize that while using the application in the Spring container, the issue still continues, but without Spring environment, surprisingly there is no such issue at all. All tests work fine, so does bi directional many to many annotation I've been dwelling on getting it work.

I'd like to hereby share the spring configuration and maven pom configuration for your observation and suggestions what to do. Briefly I manage the transactions on hibernate's side. If you see any gap or wrong I'll really appreciate your help!

Thanks again

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:hibernate.properties"/>

    <!-- Hibernate connection configuration -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${orm.connection.driver_class}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${orm.connection.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${orm.connection.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${orm.connection.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate configuration settings -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.tugrulaslan.entity"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${orm.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${orm.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${orm.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
              <!-- --> <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Session Factory creation
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/> -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tugrulaslan"/>
</beans>
```

**pom.xml**
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.tugrulaslan
    WebApp
    war
    1.0-SNAPSHOT
    BlogWebApp Maven Webapp
    http://maven.apache.org

```
<properties>
    <project-java.version>1.7</project-java.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <mysql-connector.version>5.1.34</mysql-connector.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <javax-persistance-api.version>1.0.2</javax-persistance-api.version>
    <spring.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql-connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax-persistance-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>BlogWebApp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${project-java.version}</source>
                <target>${project-java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting ? Did you tried cascade = CascadeType.ALL for ManyToMany relation ?

Comment: The error is thrown by JUnit, because the given case is not satisfied. After I edit above and check post's category size which is supposed to be 1 but it is still 2. I've tried vast of solutions and combinations which are commented out above list methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research and test, I've found out what the issue was while debugging the application. When I debugged the removal part, I did suddenly notice that the size and the elements within the Set collection is the same as before the removal operation. The equality of the object in the target collection cannot be determined, thus the removal operation cannot be proceeded.

Right after I've acknowledged this, I've promptly overridden the object equals method and included the only immutable and unalterable field(s) which only in my case seems to be the category id, the other fields are immediate-interchangeable. So the below you'll find the complete Category entity with the overridden object equals method generated by IntelliJ IDE.

Other than that, I've conducted cases for two situation to find out whether the cascade option which I happened to define above post collection defined in the Category entity is vital, mentioning "*cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}*". So eventually I've come to realize that there is no difference with the absence or existence of the corresponding cascade defined in the many-to-many relation. Its existence did not change anything experienced within other different test cases.

I hope that my issue and resolution will throw some light into the shade area and help you out if you experience similar issue.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "categoryid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long categoryId;

    @Column(name = "categoryName")
    private String categoryName;

    @Column(name = "createdDate")
    private Date createdDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_category_id")
    private Category parentCategory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCategory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Category> subCategories = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "categories")
    private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<>();

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public Category(String categoryName, Date createdDate, Category parentCategory, Set<Category> subCategories, Set<Post> posts) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.parentCategory = parentCategory;
        this.subCategories = new HashSet<>();
        if (parentCategory != null) {
            parentCategory.subCategories.add(this);
        }
        this.subCategories = subCategories;
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    public Set<Post> getPosts() {
        return posts;
    }

    public void setPosts(Set<Post> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    public long getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(long categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Category getParentCategory() {
        return parentCategory;
    }

    public void setParentCategory(Category parentCategory) {
        this.parentCategory = parentCategory;
    }

    public Set<Category> getSubCategories() {
        return subCategories;
    }

    public void setSubCategories(Set<Category> subCategories) {
        this.subCategories = subCategories;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Category category = (Category) o;

        return categoryId == category.categoryId;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) (categoryId ^ (categoryId >>> 32));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your service check if you are committing after the delete like below

```
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: I've included my method for your observation