# Delete in hibernate many to many

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

my pojos like next :

```
@Entity
    @Table(name="author_mu")
    public class Author {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int id;
        private String name;
        @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERGE,CascadeType.MERGE})
        @JoinTable(name="author_book",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="author_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="book_id"))
        private List<Book> books;

@Entity
@Table(name="book_mu")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERGE,CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name="author_book",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="book_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="author_id"))
    private List<Author> authors;
```

then used following code to do save :

```
List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<Author>();
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
        List<Author> authors2 = new ArrayList<Author>();
        List<Book> books2 = new ArrayList<Book>();

        Author a1 = new Author();
        Author a2 = new Author();
        a1.setName("harry");
        a2.setName("gelin");
        authors.add(a1);
        authors.add(a2);
        authors2.add(a2);

        Book b1 = new Book();
        b1.setName("learn java in 30 days");
        Book b2 = new Book();
        b2.setName("stock market");     
        books.add(b1);
        books2.add(b1);
        books2.add(b2);

        a1.setBooks(books);
        a2.setBooks(books2);
        b1.setAuthors(authors);
        b2.setAuthors(authors2);

        s.save(a1);
        s.save(a2); 
        s.save(b1);
        s.save(b2);
```

however, it save 6 records in áuthor_book instead of 3, that is there is duplicate records.
if I only use : s.save(a1);s.save(a2) or s.save(b1);s.save(b2), 
then error :

> org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - 
>   save the transient instance before flushing: com.my.hibernate.association.model.Book

occurred.

Thus, how to save and delete in many to many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define the mapping in both entities, so try to define the mapping in Author also:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="author_mu")
    public class Author {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int id;
        private String name;

        @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
        @JoinTable(name = "author_book",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "author_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"))
        private List<Book> books;
```

Reference these for more: 
[Hibernate Bidirectional ManyToMany delete issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155587/hibernate-bidirectional-manytomany-delete-issue)
http://outbottle.com/hibernate-manytomany-delete-non-owner-prevent-owner-being-deleted/

Comment: I tried, but this solution failed when save, please see my updated post.

Comment: yup, current it will get the duplicate when update. It's seems some limit of hibernate. But for temporary solution, you can remove this code in your save code to prevent duplicate: `a1.setBooks(books); a2.setBooks(books2)`  and change `list` to `set` in mapping. This is a trade off option, but with this you can have bidirection, delete can be in both 2 sides. Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks, this is an alternative after removing 'a1.setBooks();a2.setBooks()'